# How to restrict access of action/method (of Controller) to specific user in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, acl, fosuserbundle

Is there a way to restrict access to specific routes aka action/method of controller in Symfony based on user?

I am implementing FOSUserBundle for user management and it has roles for defining permission that works well if I have user with defined roles but if I want to restrict the page based on users I have to create role for every routes or are there any better approach.

I have looked into ACL and its perfect but I don't find solution for my case or am I missing something there.

Looking for some help and ideas.

**Updates**

@AJ Cerqueti - Answer can be quick fix but I am looking for better approach if any.

To be more specific is it possible to assign access permission for routes to user using ACL or some other better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SYMFONY >=2.6**

- [create a security voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html#creating-the-custom-voter)
- [How to Use Voters to Check User Permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html)
- [Now change the access decision strategy accordingly with the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html#changing-the-access-decision-strategy)

**SYMFONY <=2.5**

For simple needs like this you can [create a security voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html#creating-the-custom-voter) that fit exactly what you need (ACL's are usually used for complex needs also due to the not easy implementation).

Then you can use the voter in your controller like described in the docs:

```
// get a Post instance
$post = ...;

// keep in mind, this will call all registered security voters
if (false === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('view', $post)) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException('Unauthorised access!');
}
```

Read also [How to Use Voters to Check User Permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html)

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT**:

Maybe will be better to know on how many routes you want to add this behavior but in any case (and if you want to avoid to add in every controller the @AJCerqueti code) you can use a Voter like in this simple example:

Voter Class:

```
// src/AppBundle/Security/Authorization/Voter/RouteVoter.php
namespace AppBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;    

class RouteVoter implements VoterInterface
{
    private   $routes;

    public function __construct(array $routes = array())
    {
        $this->routes        = $routes;
    }

    public function supportsAttribute($attribute)
    {
        // you won't check against a user attribute, so return true
        return true;
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        // your voter supports all type of token classes, so return true
        return true;
    }

    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
    {
        // get get allowed routes from current logged in user 
        $userRoutes = $token->getUser()->getRoutes();

        // implement as you want the checks and return the related voter constant as below

        if (...) {# your implementation

            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;    
        }

        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }
}
```

Register the Voter:

```
<service id="security.access.route_voter"
     class="AppBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\RouteVoter" public="false">
<argument type="collection">
    <argument>route_one</argument>
    <argument>route_two</argument>
</argument>
<tag name="security.voter" />
```

[Now change the access decision strategy accordingly with the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html#changing-the-access-decision-strategy).

Can this fit your needs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  but the voter are object specific so far I have known, I feel good using ACL but that only supports object-scope or class scope. Here, I am looking for a way if its possible to assign access permission to users on routes using ACL or something with best approach.

Comment: Thanks @gp_sflover. Will check on that later and can I achieve this dynamically (simply using UI).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I have created a route entity and assign users to entity. Resulting user with mulitple roles for routes I will share if I get to end. Untill then, I will upvote @gp_sflover answer.

Comment: @gp_sflover where does `$token->getUser()->getRoutes();` come from? I mean where and how do these routes get stored?  Is it just a column in the users table or what?

Comment: @bought777 yeah, the `$token->getUser()->getRoutes();` refers to a column of the user table. Was only a simple example on how retrieve the allowed routes for that logged user.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with previous answers that ACLs, Voters or some sort or role-based solution is definitely the best practice approach, but for this fringe case, would suggest extending your FOSUser to add a 'slug' field, and then check on that:

```
if('accessible_slug' !== $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getSlug()) {
throw new AccessDeniedException()
}
```

This means setting up a slug for groups of controllers/actions, and setting them to the user. Similar to roles, but without quite as much overhead. Still prefer Voters and some sort of role hierarchy, but hope this helps.

Comment: That might be quick fix but I am waiting for if there is better approach.

Comment: As mentioned, the best approach is probably hierarchical role-based. I've created a little Gist for you to show you how to create a hierarchical role system in Symfony:

https://gist.github.com/ajcerqueti/a5dc10b21971493b3935

Answer (score 1):

You can use **AccessDeniedException** of Symfony2

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
```

Then check logged in User By,

```
if (false === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        } else {
Continue;
    }
```

Comment: To clarify, for controllers CRUD operation and if all users has ROLE_ADMIN but I want to allow only specific users to perform create operation and block for others. Similarly, allow assign read, update, create, delete on user basis.

Comment: So , if all users have role ROLE_ADMIN how will you differentiate between two users?

Comment: That's what I was looking for! (Possible or not?)
So, I had come with a conclusion to define role for every action/method(routes) and assign roles to user which was tedious and not a good approach. Are there any other way than this approach.
Am I clear?

Answer (score 0):

In `app/config/security.yml` there is a section `access_control:`. There you can define access restrictions for specific paths, eg.
`- { path: ^/faq/admin, roles: ROLE_FAQ_ADMIN }`

`path` argument is a regex so the above entry will restrict access to any path starting with `/faq/admin`, eg. `/faq/admin/show-something`, `/faq/admin/show-something-else` etc. Only users with specified role will have access to those paths. For other users `AccessDeniedException` will be thrown with HTTP code 403.

There is no need to change code in actions inside controllers.